# replace string if you dont' know rest of string in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, replace, wildcard

Please help. Trying to figure out how to replace a string in PowerShell, but don't know the rest of the string. I have this:

```
(Get-Content $file) -replace[regex]::Escape('file='*''),('file='+$_.BaseName) | Set-Content $file
```

I don't know what comes after `file=`

I tried my code, but it replaces it multiple times instead of just once.

So trying to replace `file=*` with `filename=$_.BaseName`.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Well, for `$_` expansion to work this needs to be inside a `Foreach-Object` loop. Then you need something like this: `(Get-Content $file) -replace '(file=).*', ('$1' + $_.BaseName) | Set-Content $file`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! After I added the extra quote '(file=).*' it worked. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI for anyone using the latest version of PowerShell Community Extensions (http://pscx.codeplex.com), there is a new command called `Edit-File` that handles this sort of thing nicely (works hard to preserve the file's original encoding):

```
Get-Item test.txt | Foreach {$bn=$_.BaseName; $_} | 
    Edit-File -Pattern '(file=).*' -Replace "`${1}$bn"
```

In theory I shouldn't need the `Foreach` stage but it seems I've found a limitation in how `-PipelineVariable` does not work with parameters that aren't pipeline bound.  Hmm, add that to the Pscx backlog.